# MySql parameterized stored procedure does not work in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have parameterized stored procedure (tested and works) in mysql.
I wanted to replace my long select statement with stored procedure in my code.
With select statement it worked but now I am not able to run it with sp (commented string req).

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetProjectVM`(
    IN projectName NVARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
   select VirtualMachines.Name,
   VirtualMachines.IpAddress,
   VirtualMachines.DiskSize,
   VirtualMachines.CPU,
   VirtualMachines.Ram,
   VirtualMachines.ImageUrl,
   VirtualMachines.Role,
   Hypervisors.Name as Hypervisor,
   Managements.Netmask,
   Managements.Gateway from VirtualMachines inner join Projects
   on Projects.id = VirtualMachines.ProjectId inner join Hypervisors
   on Hypervisors.HypervisorId = VirtualMachines.HypervisorId inner join Managements 
   on VirtualMachines.ManagementId = Managements.Id 
   where Projects.Name = projectName;
END
```

My code looks like:

```
private string _dbUrl;
private MySqlConnection _cnn;

public Dbmanagement(string dbUrl)
{
    this._dbUrl = dbUrl;
    this._cnn = new MySqlConnection(this._dbUrl);
}

private MySqlDataReader ExecuteMysqlCommand(string cmd)
{
    _cnn.Open();
    var result = new MySqlCommand(cmd, _cnn);
    return result.ExecuteReader();
} 

public IEnumerable<VM> GetProjectVM(string projectName)
{
    var vmList = new List<VM>();
    //string req =
    //    $"select VirtualMachines.Name,VirtualMachines.IpAddress,VirtualMachines.DiskSize,VirtualMachines.CPU,VirtualMachines.Ram,VirtualMachines.ImageUrl,VirtualMachines.Role,Hypervisors.Name as Hypervisor,Managements.Netmask,Managements.Gateway from VirtualMachines inner join Projects on Projects.id = VirtualMachines.ProjectId inner join Hypervisors on Hypervisors.HypervisorId = VirtualMachines.HypervisorId inner join Managements on VirtualMachines.ManagementId = Managements.Id where Projects.Name = \"{projectName}\" ;";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetProjectVM", _cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectName", projectName);          

    var req = cmd;

    var rd = ExecuteMysqlCommand(req.ToString());

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        vmList.Add(new VM(rd));
    }

    _cnn.Close();
    return vmList;
}
```

Comment: `now I am not able to run it with sp`, can you please clarify by `not able to run it` means? What happens when you set breakpoints, do you know what line is causing the problem? I see more than a few problems TBH...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem - or at least the first problem - is how you're executing the command.

Calling `ToString` on a `MySqlCommand` is very unlikely to be able to convey all the relevant information. You're losing parameterization, command type etc.

Change this:

```
var req = cmd;

var rd = ExecuteMysqlCommand(req.ToString());
```

to

```
_cnn.Open();
var rd = req.ExecuteReader();
```

I'd also suggest *not* having a single `MySqlConnection`, but just constructing one when you need to, and letting the connection pool manage making that efficient. So something like:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_dbUrl))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetProjectVM", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // Avoid AddWithValue where possible, to avoid conversion issues.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@projectName", MySqlDbType. VarChar).Value = projectName;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var list = new List<VM>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new VM(reader));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, does not adding the `.Size` of the VarChar parameter also lead to parameter sniffing? `cmd.Parameters.Add("@projectName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = projectName;`

Comment: @HardCode: I'm not sure what you mean by "parameter sniffing" but yes, it would make sense to add a size of 255 here, as declared by the SP.

Comment: @HardCode MySQL doesn't have execution plans like SqlServer to cache statements and or stored procedures, with this in mind, parameter sniffing in MySql is unlikely. MySql maintains caches for prepared statements and stored programs on a *per-session basis*. When a session ends, the server discards any statements cached for it.

Comment: Totally missed the "MySQL" part, and read it as SQL Server. Please ignore then. However, interesting information Codexer.